# Magento2 : Web services Parsing Json Data

Tags: magento2, module, web-services

I have used this below Controller to call Web service with Get method.

I got below response

[image]

I need to Parse and get the value the "Message".

my controller looks like below.

```
class Service extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            Curl $curl
        ) 
        {

            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         print_r($response);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            //echo "Welcome to Service Call";

            $curl1 = 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo';

            $this -> getMyCurlResponse($curl1);
            $resultArray = json_decode($result);
            print_r($resultArray[0]);

            if(($resultArray->status)&&($resultArray->status->message)){
                echo $resultArray->status->message;
            }

        }

}
```

I am getting Below error

```
{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded. Please use an application specific account. Do not use the demo account for your application.","value":18}}
**Error: Parse error on line 1:
...ation.","value":18}}1 exception(s):Exce
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'**
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php on line 41

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php on line 41
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\app\code\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 41, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\var\generation\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor.php(37): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service->execute()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Action\Action.php(102): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor->execute()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Autosynch\\synch...', 'dispatch', Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Autosynch\\synch...', 'dispatch', Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Autosynch\\synch...', 'dispatch', Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Autosynch\\synch...', 'dispatch', Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(91): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Autosynch\\synch...', 'dispatch', Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin.php(112): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\var\generation\Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor.php(52): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php(55): Autosynch\synchProduct\Controller\Page\Service\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#37 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#39 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento-CE\index.php(41): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#40 {main}
```

please help me, thanks In advance.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `json_decode`:

```
    class Service extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
        /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
        */
        protected $_curl;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            Curl $curl
        ) 
        {

            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_curl =$curl;
        }
         /**
         * Send SMS
         * @param type $mobile_no
         * @param type $body
         */
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

          return $response;
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            //echo "Welcome to Service Call";

            $curl1 = 'http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo';

            $result = $this->getMyCurlResponse($curl1);
            $resultArray = json_decode($result);

            if(($resultArray->status)&&($resultArray->status->message)){
                echo $resultArray->status->message;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I am getting same error:  **Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']**

Comment: Have you copied my code?

Comment: Yes, i have used your Code only. But still I am getting error I have mentioned in question.

Comment: Actually, you need to update this:

From : ` 
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

         print_r($response);
        }` 
To : `
        public function getMyCurlResponse($url)
        {
          $this->_curl->get($url);
          $response = $this->_curl->getBody();

          return $response;
        }`

Comment: Yeah, It works fine now. Thanks.  If you have time can you check this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227681/magento2-web-service-call-post-method)

Comment: Please accept my answer if it works for you, so it will help others.