# Magento2: Web service Call POST method

Tags: magento2, web-services, post-data

I wanted to call Web service using POST method and attache the Data values.

Here is my URL : http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON which takes below data in POST.

```
north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo
```

How can I Form POST URL and Call POST Web service. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked with above data but the credit usage exceeds for that user account, I tried with the new account it's working, please find the curl call below,

```
$ch = curl_init();
    $url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON";
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=chez");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($data);
    die();
```

If this answer helpful for you means, accept the answer

Comment: This is perfect for core PHP.